# Header not showing in Magento 1.9 site

Tags: magento

I am currently administering a Magento 1.9 website which hasn't been used in a long time. The site owner recently started to use the site again, and we noticed that the header section of the site is now gone. When I first set the site up, the site logo, language selector etc would show on the site header, but now that header is entirely gone ...

Initially I thought this was an issue with the language selector, so I went into the admin panel and re-configured the languages, but no dice. I've looked under all the options in the configuration section as well, but for the life of me cannot figure out why the header of the site has suddenly disappeared.

If anyone could point me to the right area in the Magento admin to take a look at this, or even how to debug etc, it would be much appreciated. The rest of the site works just fine - it is just the header (with the site logo, language switcher, login links etc) that is not showing up.

The login links are still there at the BOTTOM of the homepage - and seem to work, so I'm not sure why the header itself is not showing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks!

(Edit - I'm happy to post the site URL if need be)

Comment: Did you check browser console have any error related to the header part. Any reference related to the part will be more helpful to understand

Comment: Yes, I inspected the page Ganesh. I got four errors, but it doesn't seem like any one of them is to blame? Or maybe it is ...   I'll post them here.

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://blantotrading.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700&ampsubset=latin,cyrillic-ext'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
(index):1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #youama-email: <input type=​"text" placeholder=​"E-mail address" id=​"youama-email" name=​"youama-email" value>​ <input type=​"text" placeholder=​"E-mail address" id=​"youama-email" name=​"youama-email" value>​

Comment: (index):1 [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #youama-password: <input type=​"password" placeholder=​"Password" id=​"youama-password" name=​"youama-password" value>​ <input type=​"password" placeholder=​"Password" id=​"youama-password" name=​"youama-password" value>​
(index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://blantotrading.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700&ampsubset=latin,cyrillic-ext'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: player_api:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

(index):1303 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://blantotrading.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&key=AIzaSyBM_GojzLLfCQCRS_3BSYUSNe2TCS0vRe4&sensor=true&callback=tm_googlemap_embed_initialize'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
tm_googlemap_embed_loadScript @ (index):1303

Comment: So, these are the errors I'm getting when I inspect the page. I'm completely at a loss to understand how this could be related to the page header though (again, that is the area where the Magento site logo and login links etc should show ...).  I've checked and rechecked in the admin area, but couldn't find ANYTHING that might point me to the root cause of this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks- Gifted

Comment: I just did that ... Thanks. Yes, not about programming per se, but I must admit it has me completely perplexed!!